# Multiple occurrences of a character match using regular expression in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, i want to select a row which contains a word that is not present inside any of the angled brackets <>.

Sample Data:

```
 Row 1 --> <div class="highlight"><b>Maddy</b></div>
 Row 2 --> <div><b>This is highlighting an feature.</b></div>"
```

Here i want to filter only second row. So i used a query like

select * from table where column like '%<%>[a-zA-z0-9]*'+'highlight'+'%<%>%'"

Comment: What exactly do you want to get. Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sample Data: "Row 1 --> <div class="highlight"><b>Maddy</b></div>,"      "Row 2 --> <div><b>highlight</b></div>".... Here i want to filter only second row. So i used a query like "select * from table where column like '%<%>[a-zA-z0-9]*'+'highlight'+'%<%>%'"

Comment: 'highlight' doesn't start with 'T'.   How does this example have anything to do with your question?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more consistent? What is the problem you have in the query you applied to the sample? What characterises the rows you want to filter in general?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
LIKE 'T%[a-z]%[a-z]%'
```

Now would be a good time to familiarize yourself with what you can and cannot do with the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator.

Comment: Actually my query is little complex, i posted a simple example. I want to filter multiple occurrences of alphabets after specific symbol. So only i was not able to use '%'

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean with an example, because to me, "multiple occurrences of alphabets" is exactly what my code will give you.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

```
select * from table_name where column_name like 'T[a-z]%'

select * from table_name where column_name like '[T]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've nearly had the answer yourself Mathan.

The only problem that I can see with your code is that you were treating the `LIKE` expression as a dynamic expression.

If you are searching for a specific value in the middle of a substring then you need to wrap it in wildcards, even if you are joining search expressions together, e.g. `LIKE '%highlight% + '%<%>%'`

```
DECLARE @table table ( [column] varchar(100));

insert into @table ([column])
 SELECT * FROM 
 (
 VALUES
 ('<div class="highlight"><b>Maddy</b></div>'), 
 ('<div><b>This is highlighting an feature.</b></div>')
 ) as [table] ([column]);

 --SELECT * FROM @table;

select 
 [text_value] = PATINDEX('%<div>%', [column]) + LEN('<div>'),
  SUBSTRING(
  [column] -- what you're searching
  , PATINDEX('%<div>%', [column]) + LEN('<div>') -- after the '<div>', 
                                                 -- need to add the length of the 'div' as PATINDEX returns the starting location 
  , PATINDEX('%</div>%', [column]) - LEN('</div>')  -- until the '</div>'
  )
 , *
from @table 
    where [column] like 
        '%<%>[a-zA-z0-9]%'  -- you need to end these with the wildcard 
        +'%highlight%'      -- or SQL-Server thinks it's the end of the sentence
        +'%<%>%';
```

---

**EDIT**:

Adding in the `PATINDEX` can be used to remove the '<>' from the string. Example above removes the `<div></div>` but you can use that to remove any others as necessary e.g. `<b></b>`

Comment: If am using % that will include angled brackets know, thats my problem.